# PHP & MySQL : query if data exist and create if it not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a primary key column, containing **id** so it must be unique

the content look like this

[image]

format of **id** is `<index>/<division>/<month in roman>/<last 2 digit of year>`

> my question is what the best query to check if **id** already exist,
>   and create id with `<index>+1/<division>/<month in roman>/<last 2
>   digit of year>`

this is my function to generate id

```
    public function gen_id($id_type = "HL.BY") {
    $id_num = 123;
    $month = $this->romanic_number(date("n"));
    $year = substr(date("Y"),-2);
    $index_number = sprintf("%04d", $id_num);

    $id = $index_number . "/" . $id_type . "/" . $month . "/" . $year;
    return $id;
}
```

**if my question is not clear please ask**

Comment: Insert if not exist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: Why not make the id auto-increment? Your other data should be in separate columns, it's going to be hard to use this data down the road.

Comment: @chris85 do you mean auto-increment index_number?, unfortunately i need to use previous programmer database

Comment: Can you add a table to the existing database?

Comment: I would step back and undo (separate the data) the incorrect work the previous developer did.

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to use the existing database you can ensure unique ID's like this...

1. Create a table with two fields...

   $createSQL1 = $conn->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nxtnum` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nxtnum` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1");

   $createSQL1->execute();

   $insertSQL1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `nxtnum` (`id`, `nxtnum`) VALUES (1, 501)");

   $insertSQL1->execute();

Where "501" is the highest first-part of all existing ID's plus 1

2. Get the number for this line of your code... `$id_num = 123;` ...

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM nxtnum";
   $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();
   $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

where `$conn` is your database connection file

3. Create the new unique ID...

   public function gen_id($id_type = "HL.BY") {
   $id_num = $row['nxtnum']; // this is the new incremented number (incremented in step 4)
   $month = $this->romanic_number(date("n"));
   $year = substr(date("Y"),-2);
   $index_number = sprintf("%04d", $id_num);

   $id = $index_number . "/" . $id_type . "/" . $month . "/" . $year;
   return $id;
   }
4. Increment your counter...

   $num = $row['nxtnum'] + 1;
   $sql = "UPDATE nxtnum SET nxtnum=:num";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(':num', $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();

Now you're all set for the next ID and your ID's will always be unique

**NOTE:** Of course step one only has to be done once.